# Alternative proof for $1+2w+3w^2+\ldots+nw^{n-1}= \frac{n}{w-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers, alternative-proof

I want to prove that if $w\neq 1$ is a root of unity, then
$$F(w)=1+2w+3w^2+\ldots+nw^{n-1}= \frac{n}{w-1}$$
I have already proved it in two different ways but I am looking for a shorter and more elegant one, using derivatives. I already know that $1+w+w^2+\ldots +w^{n-1}=w+w^2+\ldots+w^n=0$. It turns out that if
$$f(w) = w+w^2+\ldots+w^n \quad \mbox{then} \quad f'(w)=F(w)$$
But $f(w)=0$ and therefore $f'(w)=0 \neq F(w)$. Am I missing something? Can't I use derivatives for this argument?

Comment: $f$ vanishes at a point $w$ does not mean $f'$ needs to.  You shouldn't use $w$ both as an arbitrary point on the complex plane (to define the function $f$) and a specific $n$-th root of unity ($f(w)=0$).

Comment: @user10354138 okay thank you. How would you finish the proof then?

Comment: If you want to use derivative: Let $f\colon z\mapsto 1+z+z^2+\dots+z^{n-1}=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$ for all $z\neq 1$.  Then we calculate $f'(z)=\frac{(z-1)nz^{n-1}-(z^n-1)}{(z-1)^2}$ and evaluate this at $\omega$.

Answer (score 5):

Your development can be understood in two ways:

- $\omega$ is a constant, namely a root of unity. Then taking the derivative on $\omega$ is pointless.
- $\omega$ is a variable, which you will *later* identify to a root of unity. In this case, $f(\omega)=0$ does not hold *yet*.

---

For an alternative proof, observe that

$$F(\omega)-\omega F(\omega)=1+\omega+\omega^2+\cdots\omega^{n-1}-n\omega^n=-n$$ and

$$F(\omega)=-\frac n{1-\omega}.$$